# Nunit Assert does not contain definition for DoesNotThrow

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, nunit, xamarin.uitest

I am trying to write a UI test for my Xamarin Forms project, taking reference from [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/SmartHotel360-Mobile/blob/master/Source/SmartHotel.Clients.UITests/BasePage.cs) Github sample, I tried to use `Assert.DoesNotThrow` but am getting an error saying that Assert does not contain a definition for `DoesNotThrow`.

**NUnit Version: 3.11.0**

Is there anything that I am missing?

[image]

Comment: Using the correct assert? i.e. `NUnit.Framework.Assert` in v2|3 contain `DoesNotThrow` and `DoesNotThrowAync`.

Comment: @SushiHangover Yes, am using the correct `Assert`. Please refer to my edited post I also attached the screenshot for the same.

Comment: Got the issue. Actually in my project I added Nunit only. After adding `NunitTestAdapter` package it's showing `DoesNotThrow` method as well, but am not able to see `DoesNotThrowAsync`. Am I missing any other package?

Comment: Is this only an Intellisense error or does it actually fail to compile. Intellisense sometimes fails to list valid methods for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the 2.6.4 version of NUnit, as the version 3.x is not supported by the Xamarin.UITest.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/